# Cardinality Estimation Decreases the performance

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

I have a db which is migrated from 2008 to 2016. But it is found that the performance of sql 2016 is much lower than 2008 I think the possibility is C.E compatibility Execution I have set the compatibility level to 130 still the issue remains same. I dont wanna change the query execution plan any other suggestion's to improve the query performances

Comment: How did you migrate the database?

Comment: how are you comparing performance,if you are you are comparing query execution time,are plans same on both instances ? how are both servers configured ?

Comment: @Manngo i used the side by side upgrade strategy

Comment: @TheGameiswar I am comparing it with the query store on the 2016 and the execution plan in 2008 the plan have changed

Comment: Are all of your indexes intact?

Comment: @Manngo They are intact